# Converting UNIX time to human time in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, code, source-code

I've a sequence of UNIX timestamps in milliseconds (e.g. 1491009470000). I want to convert them to human time in the format year-month-date-hour-minute-second (or in an array of these components). Following https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_DateNumber, I tried datestr: dt = datestr(1491009470000,'mmmm dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS'), only to have the error:

*Error using dateformverify (line 28)
DATESTR failed converting date number to date vector.
Error in datestr (line 194)
S = dateformverify(dtnumber, dateformstr, islocal);
Caused by:
    Error using datevecmx
    Date number out of range.*

Unfortunately, datevecmx doesn't seem to have a documentation in MATLAB 2014a.

However, datestr(now,'mmmm dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS.FFF AM') gives us just what we need. So, how do I get the datestr (or any other MATLAB command) to give us the human time? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The unix EPOCH is the number of seconds since jan 1 1970, so you must add datenum('1970', 'yyyy') to that number MLtime=datenum('1970', 'yyyy')+1491009470000;  datestr expects the number in seconds, not ms, so divide it by 1000 first and use the resulting number as a parameter.

Comment: @arana: I tried the following but got unexpected results:

epoch=datenum('1970', 'yyyy'); %start of unix time
>> time=epoch+1491009470000;
>> time=time/1000;
>> datestr(time)

ans =

30-Mar-2247 12:41:45

Comment: @arana: I also tried:

time=epoch+1491009470;
>> datestr(time)

ans =

12-Apr-4215.


The problem is, the times are from this year (2017), so I'm getting something wrong here. What mistake am I making? I think I followed your suggestions. Thanks again!

Comment: What do you get by datestr(1491009470) ?

Comment: @arana: here:

 datestr(1491009470)

ans =

10-Apr-2245

Comment: Online tool for conversion shows that 1491009470 is 3/31/2017, 6:17:50 PM, so your number has already the 1970 epoch included, in that case just use it as it like : time=1491009470000/1000; datestr(time), that should give you what you expect.

Comment: @arana: did that, but datestr(1491009470000/1000=1491009470)  gives me  10-Apr-2245, an impossible year, with no hour-min-second.

Comment: You didnt add the ,'mmmm dd, yyyy HH:MM:SS'), but anyway the year is just wrong,  I'm out of ideas here, check this it may give you some help https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285598